# Dynamically load in series HighCharts

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, highcharts

I am trying to dynamically load in a number of series, depending on projects chosen by the user. I am using Laravel 5.2, PHP 5.6 and HighCharts. 
I have managed to load in one JSON file, which is generated when the user selects projects. But I would like it if the JavaScript could parse the different series from the JSON file and dynamically load this into the series. 
This is the code which I am using:

```
$(function () {
    // Set up the chart
    var processed_json = new Array();
    $.getJSON('/uploads/test.json', function(data) {
        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            processed_json.push([data[i].key, data[i].value]);
        }
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'column',
                options3d: {
                    enabled: true,
                    alpha: 0,
                    beta: 0,
                    depth: 0,
                    viewDistance: 25
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Grades'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Dataset'
            },
            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    depth: 0
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Grades',
                data: processed_json
            }],

            credits: {
                enabled: false
            }
        });

        function showValues() {
            $('#alpha-value').html(chart.options.chart.options3d.alpha);
            $('#beta-value').html(chart.options.chart.options3d.beta);
            $('#depth-value').html(chart.options.chart.options3d.depth);
        }

        // Activate the sliders
        $('#sliders input').on('input change', function () {
            chart.options.chart.options3d[this.id] = this.value;
            showValues();
            chart.redraw(false);
        });

        showValues();
    });
    });
```

My JSON is formatted like:

```
[{"key":"Math","value":6},{"key":"Biology","value":"8"},{"key":"English","value":"7"},{"key":"Gym","value":"4"}]
```

So I would like to have more JSONs like so, in one file to be parsed in the Javascript and be loaded in into the series.

Thank you!

**EDIT**
thanks for your reply. I have edited my code:

```
$(function () {

var processed_json = new Array();
        var options = {    
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container',
                    type: 'column',
                    options3d: {
                        enabled: true,
                        alpha: 0,
                        beta: 0,
                        depth: 0,
                        viewDistance: 25
                    }
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Grades'
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: 'Dataset'
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    column: {
                        depth: 0
                    }
                },
                series: [{

                }],

                credits: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            };

        $.getJSON('/uploads/test.json', function(data) {
            for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                processed_json.push([data[i].key, data[i].value]);
            }
        });
            options.series[0].remove();
            options.series[0].setData = {
                name: 'Grades',
                data: processed_json
            }


        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
        chart.redraw(true);
        function showValues() {
            $('#alpha-value').html(chart.options.chart.options3d.alpha);
            $('#beta-value').html(chart.options.chart.options3d.beta);
            $('#depth-value').html(chart.options.chart.options3d.depth);
        }

        // Activate the sliders
        $('#sliders input').on('input change', function () {
            chart.options.chart.options3d[this.id] = this.value;
            showValues();
            chart.redraw(false);
        });

        showValues();

});
```

But nothing is displayed anymore and the following error is given

```
TypeError: options.series[0].remove is not a function
```

I have also tried

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
            chart.series[0].remove();
            chart.series[0].setData = {
                name: 'Grades',
                data: processed_json
            }
        chart.redraw(true);
```

But this gives:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'setData' of undefined
```

Comment: Maybe this works: 
processed_json.push({data: [{y: data[i].value, name: data[i].key}]});

Judging by the documentation found here: http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/series

Comment: Hi I tried this, but then no data is shown anymore :'(

Comment: So your original idea works? Could you show an image of this? And then maybe another image displaying how you want it to be?

Comment: Hi! My original idea works, but that is only for one JSON like I have show. I want to load in more JSONs dynamically. So, the JSON format which I am using, could be multiple times in the test.json. And then, the Javascript parses these different JSONs in multiple series and shows them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then, define method with load data.. example:

```
function(chart) {
    $.each(chart.series, function(i, v){
        chart.series[i].remove(true);
    });
    chart.addSeries({your_data}, true);
}
```

check http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Chart.addSeries/Chart.addSeries
In my webapp, i use 10 of 15 types of graphs highchart and all dynamically load and work fine :) Highcharts is awesome.

Comment: the correct link is http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Chart.addSeries

Answer (score 1):

I think highcharts has a method `chart.addSeries` for adding a new series. If you want to replace the current series with a new series, you can try removing first the current series using `chart.series[0].remove( )` then add the new series with `chart.addSeries`. The parameter for the `chart.addSeries` can be an object like your 
`{
    name: 'Grades',
    data: processed_json
}`